# What is the best way to develop web, android, desktop integrate app?

Tags: html

I have been searching this on net. I have been very confused to understand what is the best and standard way.

Comment: what are your user requirements?

Comment: if you found various ways this means there is no `"best"`. the `"best"` would depend on soooo many factors that the question - and answer - is very very individual for each project / requirements / team / goals / resources. maybe edit the question if you are looking for specific frameworks or angular / react solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Develop Across All Platforms with **Angular**.
one way to build applications with Angular and reuse your code and abilities to build apps for any deployment target. For web, mobile web, native mobile and native desktop.
**My suggestion is:
html,css,javascript,angular,nodejs,cordova.**

Comment: I also found this para in Angular.io official site. can anyone know how can we build native mobile app using Angular framework without any external framework. can one help me with an example?